# Creating Linked Lists in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, linked-list

```
typedef struct {
    NSString *activty;
    NSString *place;
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
} event;

typedef struct {
    event *thing;
    Node *next;
} Node;
```

This is the code I have in my .h file to create two structs to hold data (one for an events name/place/location, and one for the nodes of a linked list. I can use the event struct in the node struct, but I need to use the node struct within itself. In C++ this would work, but how can I achieve this in objective-c? Thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Why bother with a struct?  Just use a class:

```
@interface MyEvent:NSObject
@property(copy) NSString *activity;
@property float latitude;
... etc ...
// and that linked list gunk
@property(retain) MyEvent *nextEvent;
@end

@implementation MyEvent
@synthesize activity, latitude, nextEvent;

- (void) dealloc
{
    [activity release], activity = nil;
    [nextEvent release], nextEvent = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

There is no significant overhead vs. a structure (if the method calls are really measurable, you could even expose ivars directly).   Better yet, the moment you want to archive the struct, add business logic, or do anything else interesting, you can simply add methods.

Comment: @tc, neither is the OP's original `event` struct, bbum is pointing out that a class would be a better alternative to a vanilla C struct as per his aforementioned reasons.

Comment: There;  now it is a linked list. :)

Comment: Also, in ARC you cannot easily use objects in structs, so you'd have to use a class anyway.

Comment: Structs are way cleaner. The only reason to use a class is if it's Apple's class that comes with functions pre-made. I can't seem to find one, strangely.

Comment: @9000 Structs are way cleaner until you want to persist them.... into any Apple provided API... you want to add business logic... you want to provide various formatting logic... you want to take full advantage of ARC... etc.etc.etc...

Answer (score 2):

You need to name your structure like you would in C.  For example:

```
typedef struct Node {
    event *thing;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;
```

A better question, though, is why do you want to make this linked list in the first place?  Why not use one of the container types provided by the framework?

Comment: What would you suggest to use instead to keep multiple data types connected? Should I just store my event structs in an NSMutableArray?

Comment: That'd be the normal thing. If you want a composite approach (eg, so you can pass plain structs down to existing C code) then you can use NSValue +valueWithPointer: to create an object capable of going into an Objective-C collection but which does nothing more than point to something else.

Comment: One final question: I can't use addObject to push the struct to the array... What would be the proper way to do this? Thank you!

Comment: -1 undefined behaviour; _Node is a reserved identifier (anything starting with _[A-Z_] is in C).

Comment: @tc, good catch - in this case it's unlikely to be a problem, but easily fixed.

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll find that it doesn't work in C++ (but they might have changed the grammar rules so that it does). You probably mean something more like this:

```
struct Node {
    event *thing;
    Node *next;
};
```

That works in C++ because `Node` is equivalent to `struct Node` if there isn't already something called `Node` (this sometimes causes puzzling errors when `Foo` is both a class and the instance method of another class, which happens in some coding styles).

The fix is to say `struct Node`. I prefer this; it seems more pure. There are some good reasons to use a typedef (e.g. things like `TUInt64` which might have historically been a struct due to lack of compiler support). If you do use a typedef, there's no reason to give the struct a different name since they're in different namespaces (IIRC structs are a "tag namespace").

The usual typedef version is something like this:

```
typedef struct Node Node;
struct Node {
    event *thing;
    Node *next;
};
```

Alternatively, change the file extension to .mm and then it works because you're compiling Objective-C++!